# Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

Error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void schedule(String, String, BatchEmail) from the type System

I am trying to write a scheduler class which runs every 60 days. I am getting the error above when I try saving it. Not sure what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
 global class BatchEmails_Scheduler implements Schedulable {
         public static String sc = '0 0 18 1/60 * ? *'; 

        global static String schedule() {
                BatchEmails be = new BatchEmails(); 
                return system.schedule('Send Emails', sc, be); 
            }

            global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
                BatchEmails be1 = new BatchEmails(); 
                ID batchprocessid = database.executeBatch(be1, 100);
            }

    }
```

Comment: return system.schedule('<batch_name>', '<cron_string>', new BatchEmails_Scheduler());

Comment: I tried this, but I do not see the job in scheduled jobs after saving it. DO I need to invoke in any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass a `Batchable` implementation where `Schedulable` is expected. This is just one reason why it is better to roll both into the same class. Regardless, your `schedule` method should pass in an instance of `BatchEmails_Scheduler`:

```
return system.schedule('<batch_name>', '<cron_string>', new BatchEmails_Scheduler());
```

---

Typically, rolling them together reduces the number of classes you have to maintain and adds little overhead:

```
public with sharing class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable
{
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // batch implementation
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> records)
    {
        // batch implementation
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        // batch implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: @sfdcfox Notice the OP is trying to write a `static` scheduling method, where `this` would be undefined.

Comment: N.B. curiously, while you can mix `Database.Batchable` and `Schedulable` in the same class `implements`, you can't mix `Schedulable` and `Queueable` on the same class.